# Outside table in a row html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a table which can be seen in the attached image. The last column contains buttons and it would really be better if I could place them such that they appear outside the table but logically in the very same row. Please suggest a way to do this through bootstrap or css.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Could you show us a simple example of your code in your question - perhaps a table with headings and a couple of rows and any relevant CSS - preferably make it into a working snippet.. It is very much easier to help if we have initial code which shows the problem see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the simple case of th and td elements having the borders set but not the table we can achieve this result:
[image]

by removing the borders on the `last-of-type` th and td elements in the table.

If the table itself or rows have borders then these need to be set to border: none.

The table needs to have its borders set to collapse.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

th:last-of-type, td:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}

th {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td><input /></td>
    <td>DEL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree to the soltion.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the property `border-collapse` of the table and td elements to `collapse`, then re-setting the border on the td elements. Afterwards you just need to set `border: 0` on `td:last-child`. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3fcaqt5/4/) I made rather quickly.